# Swift HTTP request. ViewController.type does not have a member named "url"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, httprequest

I've been trying to make a HTTP request in swift using the same code found in every single tutorial and stack overflow question but I keep getting the same error; `ViewController.type does not have a member named "url"` (url being my string). My code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

task.resume()
```

The error appears on the `let task` line.

Im guessing that this is because the `url` is declared in `ViewController` and not in `ViewController.type`, but i don't see why nobody else has this problem.

(Running on xcode 6.4, using swift)

Comment: I am not getting any error. Just clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: Actually, after getting this error I made a new project with the same result. But ill try once more anyway. @DharmeshKheni

Comment: Ok let me know if it works or not.

Comment: No, still getting the same error @DharmeshKheni

Comment: Can you share sample project?

Comment: Im also getting an error on the `task.resume` line saying `expected declaration`, don't know if that makes any difference... @DharmeshKheni

Comment: ohh I understand your problem now. just declare it in your viewdidload method.

Comment: aah,  okay thanks @DharmeshKheni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
      println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }

    task.resume()
  }
```

Comment: just a follow-up question, how do i get this data into a string/variable? @dhar